# my wordpress website is suspended

Tags: security

I've got a message from the host saying that the website was suspended due to security issues.

they named a lot of files as malwares, I d've deleted all these files.

I noticed that there are a lot of random file names hidden in the main root of my website. all are php files.

now, the host is not responding, I want to restore my website as Fast as I can, what should I do??

Comment: Only your host can answer this, you might need to get a new host. Eitherway hosting issues are not in this stacks scope and are offtopic